# Artifacts in render preview after adding emission/volume scatter shader to world output volume

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, artifacts, render-passes, emission

I am following a sword tutorial and when i try to plug in either a Emission shader or Volume Scatter shader in to the world output volume node weird overexposure and artifacts appear in the render preview:
[image: Artifacts with Emission]

[image: Artifacts with Volume Scatter]

When i actually render the image it is fine. It is just the preview that is having problems. The render engine used is Eevee and i'm using blender 2.90.1.
[image: Actual render result]

Now i have tried to look at the different render passes to see if i can pinpoint the problem. The render pass bloom shows the same effects so i have tried to disable it but then it just show less glowing artifacts so i'm guessing that wasn't it.
For Emission it seems the render passes Volume Scattering and Volume Transmittance show a rather overexposed picture but only in preview mode.

Does anyone know what is causing these differences between the render preview and the actual render?

**Update:** Added blend file:
[image]

Also added

Comment: What is your setup in 3d view editor under render view properties?

Comment: @vklidu in the second image the render properties are visible or do you mean a different menu? If not Ambient Occlusion and Bloom are turned on. If turned off it simply results in less shiny artifacts. Any other settings/values you think could cause this?

Comment: I mean this one https://imgur.com/Q0bWvIJ or just if you can upload https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com simplified blend with just a part that still produce the issue (I saw already asked for the same, but I cant find it).

Comment: @vklidu it looks the same as the picture you posted. I also added the blend file to the post. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I cant reproduce your issue 2.92. Viewport and Render is the same.  You didnt pack textures, so they can make some differences, but it can be also graphic card issue??? BTW There wasnt necessary to upload whole scene (as mentioned already). Better piece with textures (in this case).

Comment: @vklidu thank you for trying! I was able to create reproduce the problem with a simplified blend file. Simply use the cube and add a emission shader to the world output volume and the artifacts appeared. I installed blender on a different laptop and was not able to reproduce just like you weren't. I think you are right and it is a graphic card issue. I am running on integrated intel hd 5200 graphics. This by itself i guess is not very well suited for rendering and to top it off i see i have a pretty old driver (2016) installed. I will try to updating the driver to see if it helps!

Comment: @vklidu it was the driver. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Since I could not find the same answer (I mentioned) I cant mark your Q as duplication ... could you please post your solution as answer here, so others can learn from your situation too? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running intel hd 520 graphics with a very old driver (2016). After updating the driver the peoblem was solved.